# Ubuntu via (Windows Linux Subsystem) and Docker

Tags: windows-10, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have started using Windows 10's Linux Subsystem and having great success using Ubuntu 14.04. No luck so far though with Docker - is this a limitation of the platform or is Docker+WLS combination going to feasible in the future?

I have quite a few scripts that need both Linux and docker presence.

Comment: There *is* a Docker for Windows; is there any particular reason you're trying to run it on the WLS environment compared to the Windows environment directly?

Comment: I know - I suppose I could configure the Ubuntu instance to connect to docker-engine via TCP but was wondering if WLS was "complete" enough to support Docker (as it would make it even closer to my linux dev machine)

Comment: I'm fairly certain WLS doesn't have all the necessary infrastructure to set up Docker.  The core issue is that WLS, while having Linux-isms, is not really truly full-featured Linux.  This is something that many are just accepting as a limitation...

Comment: Also see: http://serverfault.com/questions/767994/can-you-run-docker-natively-on-the-new-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-userspace/801138#801138

Answer (score 3):

> As of September 2016, No.
>
> All current implementations of Docker on Windows use virtualisation,
>   Docker 1.12 uses a hypervisor in Windows -thus removing the advantage
>   of containerisation over virtualisation.
>
> Docker needs more than just using Linux systems calls.
>
> It needs process control groups (cgroups), a stackable filesystem
>   (aufs), plus other Linux-based systems outside the kernel.
>
> Neither cgroups nor aufs are natively in the Windows 10 kernel.
>
> There is an implementation of Windows Server 2016 here:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server
>   ..but this will only run some Windows services, e.g. IIS, and not
>   Ubuntu

The [source](//serverfault.com/a/801138/269085) (thanks to [muru](/questions/851714/ubuntu-via-windows-linux-subsystem-and-docker#comment1309317_851714)) has answers with more detail and insight.

[Thomas](/questions/851714/ubuntu-via-windows-linux-subsystem-and-docker#comment1309216_851714) stated it quite well and short:

> I'm fairly certain WLS doesn't have all the necessary infrastructure to set up Docker. The core issue is that WLS, while having Linux-isms, is not really truly full-featured Linux. This is something that many are just accepting as a limitation…